# Query condition missed key schema element -> trying to read from dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have this dynamodb table

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.*;

@DynamoDbBean
public class ImageDetail {

    private String documentId;
    private String id;
    private int trackPosition;
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public ImageDetail() {
        // Default constructor is required for DynamoDBBean
    }

    public ImageDetail(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ImageDetail(String name, String url, double width, double height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public ImageDetail(String name, double width, double height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public ImageDetail(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }




    @DynamoDbAttribute("Name")
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("Url")
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("Width")
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("Height")
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    // Partition key
    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("Id")
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDbSortKey
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public int getTrackPosition() {
        return trackPosition;
    }

    public void setTrackPosition(int trackPosition) {
        this.trackPosition = trackPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageDetail{" +
                "documentId='" + documentId + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", trackPosition=" + trackPosition +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", width=" + width +
                ", height=" + height +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then this ImageService class:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.exiq.columbia.pdftools.model.image.ImageDetail;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;

import java.net.URI;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;


import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ImageService {

    private DynamoDbClient client;
    private DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient;
    private DynamoDbTable<ImageDetail> imagesTable;

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    public ImageService local() {
        client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:8000"))
                .region(Region.of(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")))
                .build();
        enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(client)
                .build();
        return this;
    }

    public ImageService cloud() {
        client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")))
                .build();
        enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(client)
                .build();
        return this;
    }

    public ImageService init() {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return this;
    }

    public ImageService withDefaultTable() {
        if (client == null) {
            cloud();
        }
        imagesTable = enhancedClient.table(System.getenv("COLUMBIA_IMAGES_TABLE"), TableSchema.fromBean(ImageDetail.class)); // Reflect the change here as well
        return this;
    }

    public ImageService withImagesTable(String tableName) {
        this.imagesTable = enhancedClient.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(ImageDetail.class));
        return this;
    }


    public List<ImageDetail> getImagesByDocumentId(String documentId, LambdaLogger logger) {
        List<ImageDetail> imageDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            // Query condition for the partition key only
            QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional
                    .keyEqualTo(k -> k.partitionValue(documentId));

            logger.log("Querying for DocumentId: " + documentId);

            // Enhanced client operation to query the images
            Iterator<Page<ImageDetail>> results = imagesTable.query(r -> r.queryConditional(queryConditional)).iterator();
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Page<ImageDetail> page = results.next();
                imageDetails.addAll(page.items());
            }
        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            logger.log("Error retrieving images for documentId " + documentId + ": " + e.getMessage());
            // Consider rethrowing the exception or handling it as necessary
        }

        return imageDetails;
    }



    public void saveOrUpdateImageRecords(String documentId, List<ImageDetail> imageDetails, LambdaLogger logger) {
        DynamoDbTable<ImageDetail> table = enhancedClient.table(System.getenv("COLUMBIA_IMAGES_TABLE"), TableSchema.fromBean(ImageDetail.class));

        for (int i = 0; i < imageDetails.size(); i++) {
            ImageDetail imageDetail = imageDetails.get(i);
            // Set DocumentId and TrackPosition as they are your keys.
            logger.log("image detail " + i);
            logger.log(imageDetail.toString());
            imageDetail.setDocumentId(documentId);
            imageDetail.setTrackPosition(i);
            imageDetail.setHeight(imageDetail.getHeight());
            imageDetail.setWidth(imageDetail.getWidth());
            imageDetail.setUrl(imageDetail.getUrl());
            logger.log("Processing image: " + imageDetail.getName());

            try {
                // Check if the record already exists
                ImageDetail itemToCheck = table.getItem(Key.builder()
                        .partitionValue(documentId)
                        .sortValue(i)
                        .build());

                if (itemToCheck != null) {
                    // Update the existing record
                    table.updateItem(imageDetail);
                } else {
                    // Put a new item if it doesn't exist
                    table.putItem(imageDetail);
                }
                logger.log("Operation succeeded for image: " + imageDetail.getName());
            } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
                logger.log("Unable to process image: " + imageDetail.getName());
                logger.log(e.getMessage());
                // Handle the exception based on your use case
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I perform a get query for a document id value that corresponds to existing entries in the dynamodb table I am getting this error:

Error retrieving images for documentId 2b820dad-4cf4-4a21-b243-8c0b840f56a2: Query condition missed key schema element: **DocumentId (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: B1MN9OTQVQ275DC8BGHTJVEFONVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)**

The name of the table is set correctly in the environment variables of my lambda. Attached a screenshot of the table[image]

Haven't managed to figure out what I am doing wrong yet. Any recommendations or help, very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table uses PascalCase for your key names, where I believe the Java SDK uses camelCase.

```
    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute("DocumentId")
    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }
```

Do the same for the sort key and it should work.

Comment: What about the trackPosition?

Comment: '''@DynamoDbSortKey
    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    public int getTrackPosition() {
        return trackPosition;
    }'''

Comment: Add @DynamoDbAttribute("TrackPosition")?

Comment: Yes exactly. Both keys should follow the correct casing

Comment: And a sort key should not be annotated with ignore nulls, as it can never be null.